# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

Al querer ver un dato de usuario, en la consola me tira error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
DOCTYPE is not valid JSON

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at request.onreadystatechange (functions_usuarios.js:262:32)
```

En la función esa línea es -> `let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);`

```js
function fntViewUsuario(idpersona){
    let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    let ajaxUrl = BASE_URL+'/Usuarios/getUsuario/'+idpersona;
    request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            if(objData.status)
            {
               let estadoUsuario = objData.data.status == 1 ? 
                '<span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>' : 
                '<span class="badge badge-danger">Inactivo</span>';

                document.querySelector("#celIdentificacion").innerHTML = objData.data.identificacion;
                document.querySelector("#celNombre").innerHTML = objData.data.nombres;
                document.querySelector("#celApellido").innerHTML = objData.data.apellidos;
                document.querySelector("#celTelefono").innerHTML = objData.data.telefono;
                document.querySelector("#celEmail").innerHTML = objData.data.email_user;
                document.querySelector("#celTipoUsuario").innerHTML = objData.data.nombrerol;
                document.querySelector("#celEstado").innerHTML = estadoUsuario;
                document.querySelector("#celFechaRegistro").innerHTML = objData.data.fechaRegistro; 
                $('#modalViewUser').modal('show');
            }else{
                swal("Error", objData.msg , "error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La variable *ajaxUrl* arroja el resultado como JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
{"status":true,"data":{"idpersona":"2","identificacion":"23554668","nombres":"Vendedor","apellidos":"Vendedor","telefono":"1111111111","email_user":"ventas@ventas.com","nit":null,"nombrefiscal":null,"direccionfiscal":null,"idrol":"2","nombrerol":"Vendedor","status":"1","fechaRegistro":"27-05-2022"}}
```

La dirección de la url es un JSON. De hecho, al ir a la dirección, tengo una extensión para que me formatee cuando es un JSON y lo hace de manera perfecta, pero a la hora de obtener los datos de esa url no los obtiene como JSON. Lo último que usé fue el último código:

```
let ajaxUrl = BASE_URL+'/Usuarios/getUsuario/'+idpersona;



fetch(ajaxUrl)
.then(respuesta => {
  return respuesta.json();
})
.then(objData => {
  if(objData.readyState === 4 && objData.status === 200) {

    let estadoUsuario = objData.data.status == 1 ? 
            '<span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>' : 
            '<span class="badge badge-danger">Inactivo</span>';

            document.querySelector("#celIdentificacion").innerHTML = objData.data.identificacion;
            document.querySelector("#celNombre").innerHTML = objData.data.nombres;
            document.querySelector("#celApellido").innerHTML = objData.data.apellidos;
            document.querySelector("#celTelefono").innerHTML = objData.data.telefono;
            document.querySelector("#celEmail").innerHTML = objData.data.email_user;
            document.querySelector("#celTipoUsuario").innerHTML = objData.data.nombrerol;
            document.querySelector("#celEstado").innerHTML = estadoUsuario;
            document.querySelector("#celFechaRegistro").innerHTML = objData.data.fechaRegistro; 
            $('#modalViewUser').modal('show');
    
  } else {
    swal("Error", objData.msg , "error");
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: El request no está devolviendo un JSON válido, sino seguramente HTML. ¿Qué muestra si antes de intentar invocar el parser imprimís a consola: `console.log(request.responseText);` ?

Comment: Bueno te comento a veces delvuelve la consulta como Json que es cuando anda y cuando no anda como en estos momentos lo devuelve como html como bien supones vos tenes idea porque sera. Sera el parse?

Comment: Diría que el API está mal hecha. Si algo _no anda bien_ no debiera devolver un status 200, sino otro status.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿qué dice el HTML cuándo la llamada _falla_?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al archivo a que apunta `ajaxUrl`? Debes revisar ese archivo, en él no estarías controlando adecuadamente los casos de error, resolviendo quizá con un `echo` o con un `die`. Cuando esperas un JSON del lado del cliente, en el código de servidor debes garantizar siempre un JSON, también en los casos de error. Es un fallo que veo con muchísima frecuencia en preguntas planteadas aquí basadas en código cliente / servidor tipo Ajax o Fetch.

Comment: @A. Cedano lo raro es que ajaxUrl siempre devuelve un json por que lo imprimi por consola. Cuando falla la consulta devuelve un html como una web completa en html.
ajaUrl devuelde: 
`{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "idpersona": "2",
    "identificacion": "23554668",
    "nombres": "Vendedor",
    "apellidos": "Vendedor",
    "telefono": "1111111111",
    "email_user": "ventas@ventas.com",
    "nit": null,
    "nombrefiscal": null,
    "direccionfiscal": null,
    "idrol": "2",
    "nombrerol": "Vendedor",
    "status": "1",
    "fechaRegistro": "27-05-2022"
  }
}`

Comment: Nada podemos decirte sin ver qué ocurre en ese contexto. Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: acabo de agregar la respuesta a la pregunta principal.

Comment: Entonces maneja el error cuando te regresa un HTML, usa un try-catch o puedes usar alguna condicional donde si el contenido de AjaxURL empieza con <!DOCTYPE> te mande un error, pero error manejado por ti y no uno que interrumpa la ejecución del código.

Comment: La direccion de la url es un Json de echo al ir a la direccion tengo una extencion para que me romatee cuando es un Json y lo hace de manera perfecta. Pero a la hora de obtener los datos de esa url no los obtiene como json lo ultimo que use fue el ultimo codigo que agrego a la pregunta.